# Multiple definition error using header file

Tags: c

When I try to compile my program with header file in gcc I get error like this:
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\37069\AppData\Local\Temp\ccnYwij4.o:file2048.c:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `matrix'; C:\Users\37069\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGaOCe4.o:namudarbas2.c:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

matrix is only initialized in my header file.

Header file:

```
#ifndef FILE2048_H
#define FILE2048_H
#define SIZE 4

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int matrix[SIZE+1][SIZE+1]={0};
int score;
    
void saveToFile(void);
void start(void);
void reset(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Other file with function defined:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "file2048.h"

void saveToFile(){
    FILE *load=fopen("2048.txt", "w");
    fprintf(load, "%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d\n%d %d %d %d\n%d", matrix[0][0], matrix[0][1], matrix[0][2], matrix[0][3], matrix[1][0], matrix[1][1], matrix[1][2], matrix[1][3], matrix[2][0], matrix[2][1], matrix[2][2], matrix[2][3], matrix[3][0], matrix[3][1], matrix[3][2], matrix[3][3], score);
    fclose(load);
}
void start(){
    FILE *load=fopen("2048.txt", "r");
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++){
            fscanf(load, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    fscanf(load, "%d", &score);
    fclose(load);
}
```

And a bit of my main file, where I try calling the function I created in my other file:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "file2048.h"

#define UP 72
#define DOWN 80
#define LEFT 75
#define RIGHT 77
#define ESC 57

int over=0;
int last=0;

void display(){
    system("cls");
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        printf("\n\n\n");
        for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    saveToFile();
    printf("Your score - %d", score);
}
```

Any help where the problem could be? I'm new with header files.

Comment: You should not "define" (either implicitly or explicitly allocate space for) a variable in your headers.

Comment: so it should be defined in main?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header file `file2048.h` contains variable declarations. When you include this file in other sorces files this causes the variable to be declader multiple times. Please look into the `extern` keyword.

**Header File:**

```
#ifndef FILE2048_H
#define FILE2048_H
#define SIZE 4

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* - Bad implementation
int matrix[SIZE+1][SIZE+1]={0};
*/

//Better implementation
extern int matrix[SIZE+1][SIZE+1];
//Now define this variable only once, on "main.c" for example

.
.
.

#endif
```